# jira updated field doesn't limit respond

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm currently interested in automation of some of our processes, so I need to query JIRA with REST. What I want to have in response is timespent of all users for a certain date. So I use the following queries:

```
search?jql=project=%my_project%22&updated&gt;startOfDay(-1d)&updated&lt;endOfDay(-1d)&fields=worklog

search?jql=project=%my_project%22&updated&gt;%222014-08-19%22
```

but in response I get a lot of worklogs which was updated not only the date I pass as argument but a month before or a day after.

So I have several questions:

1. Am I understand right that if I track time for some issue then the updated field will be changed?
2. It is likely that my queries return issues which was updated for a given date in the first place. I mean if issue was updated - return it, but issue itself contains a lot of worklogs for some period of time (month I guess).

If it is true then can I limit worklogs for the issues for only given dates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, you can limit your query in a way like this. But I guess your syntax is invalid.

1. First, in both of your query, after the project part of the JQL, there's a single percentage sign, which cannot be interpreted as a char. I'm sure you wanted to write `%22` there. (However, you can  completely omit `%22` char)
2. Second, the JQL part of your query string must be formed with the official JQL syntax in mind. That means when you use logical operators, like AND, then you must write that in the middle of the query. And also don't replace `>` with `&gt;`. So, instead of

`project=my_project&updated&gt;%222014-08-19%22`

the query must look like

`project=my_project AND updated>2014-08-19`

Note: `&` sign can only split the [official query string parameters](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e423) of the request.